# A problem on completeness of lattice from Neukirch algebraic number theory book.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The question is: Show that a lattice $T$ in $R^n$ is complete if and only if the quotient $R^n/T$ is compact.

I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by reminding yourself (and us) what it means for a lattice to be complete, and what it means for a quotient to be compact.

Comment: Yeah I know both the definitions. But can't use it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you going to keep them to yourself?

Comment: A lattice $T$ in $R^n$ is complete if and only if there exists a bounded subset $M \subseteq R^n$ such that the collection of all translate $M +a$ , $a \in T$ , covers the entire space. Then how will I use this to show that in the quotient, every open cover has a finite subcover? Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:  Consider the natural projection map $p : R^n \rightarrow R^n/T$ which is continuous, then image of the set $A = \{\ x_{1}v_{1}+ \dots + x_{n}v_{n} | 0 \leq x_{1} \leq 1 \}\ $ is $R_n/T$ where $v_{i}$'s are basis of $R^n$ and A is compact so as the image. Is it correct?

Comment: My advice is to post that as an answer to the question, and see what people think.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.